# Trouble with aliases (Invalid Column Name)

Tags: sql

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to make aliases work properly.  I have a complicated query that includes the same table twice: `HIFIS_Services`. One is given the alias `HIFIS_Services_Goods` and the other is given the alias `HIFIS_Services_Stay`.  Of course, they both include the same columns so I've renamed `HIFIS_Services_Goods.ServiceID` to `GoodsServiceID`.

This is my initial query that works fine:

```
SELECT 
vw_Stays.ClientID, 
vw_Stays.LastName, 
vw_Stays.FirstName, 
HIFIS_Places.Name AS ReferrerName, 
vw_Stays.RoomName AS MotelName, 
HIFIS_ReasonForGoodsActivityTypes.NameE AS ReasonForMotel, 
HIFIS_UnitOfMeasureTypes.NameE AS RoomType, 
vw_Stays.StayID, 
HIFIS_Services_Stay.DateStart AS StayStart, 
HIFIS_Services_Stay.OrganizationID AS StayOrganizationID, 
HIFIS_Services_Goods.OrganizationID AS GoodsOrganizationID, 
HIFIS_Services_Goods.ServiceID AS GoodsServiceID, 
HIFIS_Services_Goods.ServiceTypeID, 
HIFIS_Services_Goods.DateStart AS GoodsStart, 
vw_Stays.BedDateStart, 
vw_Stays.BedDateEnd, 
vw_Stays.StayDateStart, 
vw_Stays.CurrentAge, 
HIFIS_Goods.GoodTypeID, 
HIFIS_Goods.UnitPrice, 
HIFIS_Groups.GroupTypeID, 
HIFIS_People_Groups.PeopleGroupID, 
HIFIS_People_Groups.DateEnd AS FamilyEnd, 
HIFIS_People_Groups.DateStart AS FamilyStart, 
HIFIS_Services_Stay.FromReferrerPlaceID, 
HIFIS_Services_Goods.Comments


FROM   ((((((((((vw_Stays 
INNER JOIN HIFIS_Services AS HIFIS_Services_Stay ON vw_Stays.ServiceID=HIFIS_Services_Stay.ServiceID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN HIFIS_Client_Services AS HIFIS_Client_Services_Goods ON vw_Stays.ClientID=HIFIS_Client_Services_Goods.ClientID) 
INNER JOIN HIFIS_Clients ON vw_Stays.ClientID=HIFIS_Clients.ClientID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN HIFIS_Services AS HIFIS_Services_Goods ON HIFIS_Client_Services_Goods.ServiceID=HIFIS_Services_Goods.ServiceID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN HIFIS_GoodsActivities ON HIFIS_Services_Goods.ServiceID=HIFIS_GoodsActivities.ServiceID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN HIFIS_Goods ON HIFIS_GoodsActivities.GoodsActivitiesID=HIFIS_Goods.GoodsActivitiesID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN HIFIS_ReasonForGoodsActivityTypes ON HIFIS_GoodsActivities.ReasonForGoodsActivityTypeID=HIFIS_ReasonForGoodsActivityTypes.ID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN HIFIS_UnitOfMeasureTypes ON HIFIS_Goods.UnitOfMeasureTypeID=HIFIS_UnitOfMeasureTypes.ID) 
INNER JOIN HIFIS_Places ON HIFIS_Services_Stay.FromReferrerPlaceID=HIFIS_Places.PlaceID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN HIFIS_People_Groups ON HIFIS_Clients.PersonID=HIFIS_People_Groups.PersonID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN HIFIS_Groups ON HIFIS_People_Groups.GroupID=HIFIS_Groups.GroupID

WHERE  HIFIS_Services_Stay.OrganizationID=2 

AND PeopleGroupID = (
SELECT PeopleGroupID
    FROM HIFIS_People_Groups
    INNER JOIN HIFIS_Groups ON HIFIS_People_Groups.GroupID = HIFIS_Groups.GroupID
    WHERE GroupTypeID=1
)
```

However, when I add the following clause, I get `Invalid column name: GoodsServiceID`.

If I just use `ServiceID`, I get `Ambiguous column name`.

If I use `HIFIS_Services_Goods.ServiceID`, I get `Invalid object name: HIFIS_Services_Goods`.

If I try `HIFIS_Services.ServiceID` or `HIFIS_Services.GoodsServiceID`, I get `The multi-part identifier could not be bound`.

```
AND GoodsServiceID = (
SELECT ServiceID
    FROM ((((HIFIS_Services_Goods
    INNER JOIN HIFIS_Client_Services HIFIS_Client_Services_Goods ON vw_Stays.ClientID=HIFIS_Client_Services_Goods.ClientID) 
    INNER JOIN HIFIS_Services HIFIS_Services_Goods ON HIFIS_Client_Services_Goods.ServiceID=HIFIS_Services_Goods.ServiceID)
    INNER JOIN HIFIS_GoodsActivities ON HIFIS_Services_Goods.ServiceID=HIFIS_GoodsActivities.ServiceID)
    INNER JOIN HIFIS_ReasonForGoodsActivityTypes ON HIFIS_GoodsActivities.ReasonForGoodsActivityTypeID=HIFIS_ReasonForGoodsActivityTypes.ID) 
    INNER JOIN HIFIS_UnitOfMeasureTypes ON HIFIS_Goods.UnitOfMeasureTypeID=HIFIS_UnitOfMeasureTypes.ID
WHERE HIFIS_Services_Goods.OrganizationID=2 
AND HIFIS_Goods.GoodTypeID=1000 
AND HIFIS_Services_Goods.ServiceTypeID=31
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Holly Parentheses! Surely all those joins can use a little less encapsulation?

Comment: Does the `SELECT ServiceID FROM ((((....))))` query return expected results? Also is the `ServiceID` a constant?

Comment: You can remove those parentheses from your internal query  `SELECT ServiceID FROM ((((....))))`

Comment: Btw, some of the RDBMS don't like it when you don't give an alias to a subquery.  Also `AND x = (select ... from ...)` is sometimes asking for trouble. Use an IN, or EXISTS, or limit the subquery to only retrieve 1 record.

Comment: @LukStorms they probably can.  Told you I'm new! I am modifying an existing SQL statement generated via Crystal Reports.

Comment: Ouch, generated SQL...  Heh, that explains the long alias names.

Comment: @Aureate thanks, I removed them but that doesn't get me closer to a solution.

Comment: @LukStorms I'm not really sure what RDBMS means.  Anyways, I really do only want to retrieve 1 record with my `AND x = (SELECT... FROM...)` statements

Comment: @Nathan I'm not positive, since I haven't got it to run yet

Comment: RDBMS = [Relational Database Management System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system).  So it's the type of database. Oracle, Teradata, MS SQL Server, MySQL, MariaDB, ... just to name a few.  SQL has a standard, but there's a lot of SQL statements that are specific to them.

Comment: For example, in MS SQL Server you could do a `where x IN (select val from table)` or `where x = (select top 1 val from table)`.

Comment: maybe one thing to keep in mind is that inside a subquery each name should be unique. F.e. this should fail: `select bar from(select foo as bar, bar from foobar) q`  Because how would the database know which bar you need?